# Everything on my website is properly resizing for mobile except for a single element, and I cannot figure out why?

Tags: html, css

Pretty much the title. Please see the code for the `<a>` tag:

```
 <header class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-grayscale-min" id="home">
  <div class="w3-hide-small w3-display-left w3-text-white" style="padding:48px">
    <span class="w3-jumbo w3-hide-small">Name</span><br>
    <p><a class="w3-mobile w3-responsive w3-hide-small w3-button w3-white w3-padding-large w3-large w3-margin-top w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off">random text here</a></p>
  </div> 
  <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-text-grey w3-large" style="padding:24px 48px">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter w3-hover-opacity"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  </div>
</header>
```

This is CSS and Libraries used in the webpage. Here is some more random text because I am getting a post is mostly code error:

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.8;
  ;
}

/* Full height image header */
.bgimg-1 {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("/images/Background.jpg");
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: 100%;
}

.w3-bar .w3-button {
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
}

</style>
```

Comment: we don't know which element isn't resizing....

Comment: My mistake! Fixed

Comment: you have no classes on the `<p>` element

Comment: I mean the <a> class inside the <p>. I'm sorry for the confusion!

Comment: is that why you down voted my answer?

Comment: Can you add your CSS or what libraries you're using to style this?

Comment: Sure adding now to original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no classes on the `<p>` element itself and therefore no CSS is being applied to it. Tons on the `<a>`, none on the `<p>`

Comment: I didn't downvote, I dont even have enough points to do so. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Oh okay, someone just felt like sharing their pain I guess then. I'm going to quit trying to help now, good luck with your problem.

Comment: Yeah pretty odd... Thanks for trying!

Comment: at the risk of getting another down vote with no explanation, you should probably change your question to say `<a>` instead of the word paragraph

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip

Comment: well whoever it was can't down vote my answer for no reason twice so.... I've never used W3school's CSS stuff, but I still think you need to some classes on that `<p>` element

Comment: This is true. I tried adding the necessary styles to the <p> element, and that solved the issue! Thanks for the help!